# Magento 1.9 :Product images missing in backend but not in the frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, product-images

I am Facing an issue,that product images are missing from ‘Images’ tab of product edit form, but they are displaying fine in the front-end.

Screenshort:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused by wrong permissions set to uploaded files. Open `lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php` and make sure the following permission are set:

Around line 219:

```
chmod($destinationFile, 0666);
```

Around line 541:

```
if (!(@is_dir($destinationFolder) || @mkdir($destinationFolder, 0777, true))) {
```

Resource: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35911378/5607415

Comment: Please accept the answer if it works for you, So it will help others in the community.